# Does CakePHP have a Model->find equivalent that return an array of Objects?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

CakePHP returns nested arrays and no collections of objects for the `Model->find` method.
Does CakePHP offer a way to retrieve a collection of Models?

Comment: Just curiosity. Why do you need the info as an array of objects?

Comment: Let us assume that we need to use Cake for this job. Given a table of Nodes, each with different properties and some connection information. (This could also be stored in a separate Edge table).

This set of Nodes constitutes a Graph upon which one might want to perform some optimization. In this case it can be very helpful to have "intelligent" Nodes. E.g. nodes that contain logic. This as I understand is not possible with Cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Set` class](http://api.cakephp.org/class/set) to [map arrays to objects](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1505/map) (and [back again](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1491/reverse)) as outlined in [this blog post](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/28/i-want-objects-not-arrays/).

CakePHP (back in the PHP 4 compatibility days) chose to use arrays over objects as PHP is packed full of array manipulation functions that make working with arrays easy. PHP loves arrays so I suppose it made sense to balance PHP's strengths with good design patterns at the time.

I believe CakePHP 2.0 models will still return arrays (I assume for backwards-compatibility), though you may want to look at the [Lithium framework](http://lithify.me/) - which started life intending to be CakePHP 3.0 (supporting only PHP 5.3+) - or another of the PHP 5+ frameworks out there.

These newer frameworks tend to take fuller advantage of PHP 5's [newer OOP features](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/lithium-basics/new-in-php53.wiki) and tend to return records as objects (see: models in Lithium [API](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/data/Model) and [manual](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/using-models.wiki)).

Answer (score 1):

No, like it or not, cake uses multidimensional arrays as data (for the usual CRUD functions). But if you want to, you could redefine the find method to map the array into objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert in afterFind(). But why do you need that?